# `sum() over()` without/with `order by`

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, window-functions

In mysql, if you use `sum(some_col) over()`, it will return global sum for each row. But when you use `sum(some_col) over(order by some_col)`, it will give different cumulative sum in two case: whether `some_col` has duplicate value.

```
create table if not exists tsum (
    num1 int,
    num2 int
);
truncate table tsum;
insert into tsum values (2,1), (2,2), (1,3), (1,4), (3,5);
# select * from tsum;

select *, sum(num1) over (order by num1) as c1
from tsum;
select *, sum(num2) over (order by num2) as c2
from tsum;
```

result is

```
num1, num2, c1
1,3,2
1,4,2
2,1,6
2,2,6
3,5,9

num1, num2, c2
2,1,1
2,2,3
1,3,6
1,4,10
3,5,15
```

Why using `order by` will give cumulatve sum? Why cumulative sum would be different when there are duplicate value from ordered `some_col`(e.g. I expect `c1` would be `1, 2, 4, 6, 9`)?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) explains the base concepts:

> An `ORDER BY` clause indicates how to sort rows in each partition. Partition rows that are equal according to the `ORDER BY` clause are considered peers. If `ORDER BY` is omitted, partition rows are unordered, with no processing order implied, and all partition rows are peers.

The window sum behaves accordingly, and considers *peer rows* when doing the computation:

- without an `order by`, all rows are summed together.
- when the `order by` clause is there but generates ties, these are peers, that are summed together.
- when the `order by` is determinstic, there are no peers and each row gets a different result

Comment: Thanks. I also read that document before, but I couldn't understand how `sum` is related to `peer rows`?